# How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?

Tags: terminal, applescript, macos, notifications, command-line

I'd love to be able to take advantage of 10.8's Notification Center features in AppleScripts and shell scripts I write.

Is there a built-in command or a third-party library I can use from either an AppleScript or shell script?

Ideally the type and icon of the notification could be controlled, but even just the ability to trigger a basic banner with a stock icon (but custom text) would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24606225/redirected-to-applescript-editor-on-clicking-apple-notification

Comment: Just to add that this is also possible in Apple's Shortcuts and Automator apps with, respectively, the Show Notification and Display Notification actions.

Answer (score 552, accepted):

With Mavericks and later, you can do this using AppleScript's 'display notification':

```
display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"
```

[image]

That's it—literally that simple! No 3<sup>rd</sup>-party libraries or apps required and is completely portable for use on other systems. 10.9 notification on the top, 10.10 DP in the middle, 10.10 on the bottom.

AppleScript can be run from the shell using /usr/bin/osascript:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'
```

You can also customise the alert further by adding…

- a subtitle

  Append 'subtitle' followed by the string or variable containing the subtitle.

  ```
  display notification "message" with title "title" subtitle "subtitle"
  ```

  The above example produces the following notification:

  [image]
- sound

  Append 'sound name' followed by the name of a sound that will be played along with the notification.

  ```
  display notification "message" sound name "Sound Name"
  ```

  Valid sound names are the names of sounds located in…

  - `~/Library/Sounds`
  - `/System/Library/Sounds`

---

Posting notifications can be wrapped as a command-line script. The following code can be run in Terminal and will add a script to /usr/local/bin (must exist, add to $PATH) called `notify`.

```
cd /usr/local/bin && echo -e "#!/bin/bash\n/usr/bin/osascript -e \"display notification \\\"\$*\\\"\"" > notify && chmod +x notify;cd -
```

This is the script that the above will add to notify.

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/osascript -e "display notification \"$*\""
```

Now to display a notification:

```
notify Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
sleep 5; notify Slow command finished
```

Comment: What is the path of `display`? I have Mavericks but I can't see to find it. Thanks!

Comment: @ceilingcat Could you clarify what you mean? What doesn't work?

Comment: I got `-bash: display: command not found` My path is kind of screwy though, so it would be nice to know exactly where `display` is located.

Comment: @ceilingcat This is AppleScript. To run it in Terminal, use osascript (see answer).

Comment: The only problem with `display notification` is that when you click on it, the open file dialog appears.

Comment: Is it possible to make the notificatiop popup exist forever (not auto-hide after N seconds) until explicitly clicked by the user?

Comment: How do I add a time limit for the notification to exist on the screen ?

Comment: Couple of questions - 1. Any way I can add certain actions on click of the notification? Say I want to run a certain shell script. I am on Yosemite, and it launches file browser. 2. How do I customize the notification with more options, like show a button within at the side on hovering over it, like what happens when the next iTunes song autoplays and notification appears showing that song, or when you click on the notification when you have a new message, two options come up - Send and Cancel?

Comment: Nothing I've found indicates that there's a way to control the action (what happens when you click on the notification). http://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/notifications/01.html is handy, FYI.

Comment: Ladies and gentlemen, after an hour of investigation on the world wide web, I have found out how to let the notification window stay until dismissed by user!

It was actually controlled by a setting in System Preference, rather than some parameter in the script written.

These two images should explain it all
http://i.imgur.com/cNOqFyX.jpg http://i.imgur.com/i8oyoan.jpg
Have fun guys, and thanks @grgarside for the great answer.

Comment: Note that the text has to be in double quotes. Single quotes don't work. So if you need a variable in the text, you cannot write `"display ... '$mytext' ..."`, but need escaped double quotes:  `"display notification \"$mytext\" ..."`.

Comment: `display notification` isn't working for me on El Capitan, although `display alert` works fine. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224) claims both work. Any insight into this?

Comment: As Vic Jang mentioned but did not clearly explain, you can change the settings for how the notifications are displayed via System Preferences > Notifications > Script Editor > change from "Banners" to "Alerts". That way you can at least click "Close" instead of seeing the Open File dialog when you dismiss the notification.

Comment: @Dan Clicking a notification is *never* a dismiss action, which is why Script Editor is launched when clicking. You can dismiss a banner with a two finger swipe whilst hovering it. I may look into alternatives if I have time at some point.

Comment: custom image for notification?

Comment: Seems like `sound name` doesn't allow you to play custom sounds in `~/Library/Sounds` anymore. Anybody know a fix? Using macOS 10.13.2.

Comment: On Mac 11.2.3: `zsh: command not found: display`

Comment: @Alik Please read answer, specifically: ‘AppleScript can be run from the shell using /usr/bin/osascript’

Comment: I had to kill the "Notification Center" process which restarts automatically, before the notification started popping up.

Comment: @noɥʇʎԀʎzɐɹƆ was wondering that too, but [`display notification` doesn't appear to take an image parameter](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW224), just `title`, `subtitle`, and `sound name`

Comment: Starting in macOS Ventura, I now have to toggle on `Allow notifications when mirroring or sharing the display` if I want notifications to show when using external monitors (even when _not_ mirroring)

Answer (score 113):

## [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier)

From the README:

> terminal-notifier is a command-line tool to send Mac OS X User
>   Notifications, which are available in Mac OS X 10.8.
>
> It is currently packaged as an application bundle, because
>   `NSUserNotification` does not work from a ‘Foundation tool’.
>   radar://11956694
>
> This tool will be used by [Kicker](https://github.com/alloy/kicker) to
>   show the status of commands which are executed due to filesystem
>   changes. (v3.0.0)
>
> ### Download
>
> Prebuilt binaries, which are code-signed and ready to use, are
>   available from the [downloads
>   section](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier/downloads).
>
> ### Usage
>
> `$ ./terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS/terminal-notifier
>   group-ID sender-name message [bundle-ID]`
>
> In order to use terminal-notifier, you have to call the binary
>   *inside* the app bundle.
>
> The first argument specifies the ‘group’ a notification belongs to.
>   For any ‘group’ only *one* notification will ever be shown, replacing
>   previously posted notifications. Examples are: the sender’s process ID
>   to scope the notifications by a unique process, or the current working
>   directory to scope notifications by a project.
>
> The second and third arguments describe the notification itself and
>   are its ‘title’ and ‘message’ respectively. For example, to
>   communicate the sender of a notification to the user, you could
>   specify the sender’s name as the title.
>
> The fourth and last argument is an optional one. It specifies which
>   application should be activated when the user clicks the notification.
>   By default this will activate Terminal.app, to launch another
>   application instead specify the application’s bundle identifier. For
>   example, to launch Safari.app use: `com.apple.Safari`.

Comment: Sweet, a great library! Would love to see it updated with control over the icon and alert vs banner, but definitely useful. Thanks for the link! http://i.imgur.com/tsCeK.png

Comment: Great little app, I created a launcher and put in /usr/local/bin so that I can use it anywhere from a terminal etc. Launcher script: #!/bin/bash cd /Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS ./terminal-notifier $*

Comment: Launcher is helpful, if you change it a bit it works with quoted text with spaces:
#!/bin/bash
cd /Applications/terminal-notifier.app/Contents/MacOS 
./terminal-notifier "$@"

Comment: Easy to use. But does not work in cronjobs for some reason. I am getting `sh: terminal-notifier: command not found`

Comment: @Nabin does the user who runs the cron have `brew` bin directory in the `$PATH variable? By default it does not...

Answer (score 47):

I just want to add a note to @grgarside's answer, because I know many people want to have a notification popup that can only be dismissed by button click.

[image: Comparison]

I have found the solution for you:

It was actually controlled by a setting in System Preference, rather than some parameter in the script written. These two images should explain it all

Thanks @grgarside for the great answer.

[image: System Preference]

Comment: Note that the specific app will vary. `Script Editor` is only for `Script Editor.app` and `osascript`. In a service workflow, it's `Automator Runner`. When inside `Automator.app`, it's `Automator`.

Comment: I find it annoying that if I click on the Banner, it brings up the Script Editor application.  I'd like for it to just disappear on click, but this post points out you can hover over it and trackpad-swipe right to make it go away quietly: http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/05/dismiss-notifications-os-x-quickly-swipe/

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Thanks for adding that! I found that out intuitively one day, which is one thing I like about Mac OS X, it works the way you expect it do work :)

Comment: Trying to use the `osascript` command was suddenly not working, neither in iTerm nor in Terminal, until I went to the Notifications settings for Script Editor and changed it from “None” to “Banners”!

Comment: I had intermittent problems with getting the `display notification` to run successfully; sometimes it would work, other times it would just be silent. After months of this frustrating behavior, I finally discovered it was caused by [Do Not Disturb](https://i.imgur.com/oTaNX9a.png), which I had scheduled to activate after 8pm. ‍♂️

Comment: This doesn't seem to work anymore (Big Sur anyway)...

Answer (score 23):

You can now do this with Growl2 ([available from the App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/be/app/growl/id467939042?mt=12)). Install Growl and enable "OS X Notifications" (screenshot)

[image]

Additionally, you'll need to install GrowlNotify for a command-line tool to send Growl notifications. You can download this tool for free on the [Download page](http://growl.info/downloads#generaldownloads).

You can now generate Growl notifications from the command line, which will be forwarded to the Notification Center. For example:

```
growlnotify -n "My App" -m "Hello world"
```

[image]

Note that it currently doesn't seem possible to change the application icon.

Comment: Nice approach especially if growl is installed already.

Comment: I think you might be able to use the option `--icon path/to/icon.png` for icons.

Comment: Deprecated/no longer maintained? Last update was for macos 10.9 *mavericks*

Answer (score 19):

[@grgarside](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/37797/grgarside)'s [solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115373/51411) is nice, but it is vulnerable to script injection, which can be a major security issue when this is used to e.g. display log file contents or something similar.

This should be safer:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
X="$*" /usr/bin/osascript -e 'display notification system attribute "X"'
```

Comment: this is interesting, but can you describe a scenario where a script I run on my system that is only user-executable is vulnerable to script injection?

Comment: If you display user content that is not from you, you are vulnerable. For example if you run this on a system with a public web server, or when some app logs strings it got from the net which you read and display, e.g. a browser, mail program or a Twitter client. It could have a " to end the string and statement, then have code and then restart a string.

Comment: okay, that's true.  it's just hard for me to imagine ever putting content from web forms into my notifications, but your point is taken.

Comment: Well, maybe you'd just like to say something like `I have a "laser"` without being told you're having a syntax error by "quoting" your "words". With escaping, you can: `script 'I have a "laser"'`

Comment: Upvote because it's always good to keep security in mind. Someone could copy-pasta solutions and use them in ways the person posting the solution hadn't considered.

Comment: I just played with it; that idiom seems to only escape one quote. Is there a "global" version?

Comment: @EdwardFalk the substitution was missing a slash. Should work now.

Comment: If you want to use escaping, you must escape \ -> \\ as well, otherwise \" becomes \\" and you can break out. I changed the example to use an environment variable instead.

Answer (score 18):

I recently forked terminal-notifier to build a command line tool to display notification Alerts (with actions) and Reply Type Alerts.

I use it with my shell scripts and golang apps to get interactive answers from users.

https://github.com/vjeantet/alerter

[image]

Comment: Also apparently deprecated/abandoned.

Comment: Looks alive and well now.

Answer (score 17):

(This is an alternative implementation based on @grgarside's excellent answer.)

AppleScript can be interpreted directly by putting `osascript` in the shebang line.

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on run argv
    if length of argv = 1 then
        display notification (item 1 of argv) with title "Notification"
    else if length of argv > 1 then
        display notification (item 1 of argv) with title (item 2 of argv)
    else
        return "<message> is required\nUsage: notify <message> [<title>]"
    end if
end run
```

Save this as `notify` somewhere in your path, e.g., `/usr/local/bin/notify`, and make it executable (`chmod +x notify`).  It accepts a message and an optional title.  If either has whitespace, wrap it in quotes so the shell interprets it as a single argument.

```
$ notify "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" "Testing Notifications"
```

Comment: This avoids the injection attacks that all the other answers are vulnerable to

Comment: Nice script, thanks!  Note that "notify" is a built-in shell command in some commands (like mine, tcsh), so you might need to use a different name, as I did.

Comment: Is there a way to make the notification sticky, so it requires a click to dismiss?

Comment: @CraigS.Anderson - one of the other answers (by Vic Jang) indicates that this is determined by the user's System Preferences (under Notifications > Script Editor).  I'm not aware of a scripted way to do one or the other.

Answer (score 16):

Since Growl is not free, and terminal-notifier is not available on pre-10.8 systems, I tend to use [cocoaDialog](https://github.com/cocoadialog/cocoadialog). It is free and open source, so you can probably also distribute along with your scripts.

If you don't need a lot of customization, you can also use AppleScript's `display notification` which you can also call from the shell as others have already mentioned.

But beware that AppleScript seems to require double-quotes. So if you need variables, this **will not work**:

```
osascript -e "display notification '$text' with title '$title'" #WRONG
```

You will have to use escaped double-quotes. This is ugly **but works**:

```
osascript -e "display notification \"$text\" with title \"$title\""
```

Comment: This also works: `osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'`

Comment: Also deprecated. Link yields "There isn't a GitHub Pages site here."

Answer (score 9):

Here's a cool one that I use in a ruby script on OS X (so that I can start a script and get an update even after toggling away from the window):

```
cmd = %Q|osascript -e 'display notification "Server was reset" with title "Posted Update"'|
system ( cmd )
```

Comment: wow... so the chain is something like User -> Ruby -> Shell -> AppleScript -> Objective-C -> Assembly -> CPU?

Comment: Coming at this late, but for the record, for convenience, I wrote a LISP wrapper for the Ruby command, and I typed it in with the mechanical arms from one of those giant P-5000 Powered Work Loader mechanical exoskeletons like Ripley wore in _Aliens_.

Comment: @JohnSmith This is precisely why I read all the comments on SE posts.

Comment: @johnsmith good point. We obviously should be wrapping this in a docker container, then deploying it with Kubernetes using a CI/CD pipeline. :)

Answer (score 8):

### An alternative:

In `.bash_profile`:

```
function _sys_notify() {
    local notification_command="display notification \"$2\" with title \"$1\""
    osascript -e "$notification_command"
}
alias sys-notify="_sys_notify $1 $2"
```

Use command: `sys-notify "title" "message"`

Answer (score 5):

Official documentation

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayNotifications.html

Copying the text here, in case the document is moved or removed.

> To show a notification, provide the display notification command with a string to display. Optionally, provide values for the with title, subtitle, and sound name parameters to provide additional information and an audible alert when the notification appears
>
> ```
> display notification "All graphics have been converted." with title "My Graphic Processing Script" subtitle "Processing is complete." sound name "Frog"
> ```
>
> NOTE
>
> After using a script to display a notification, the script or Script Editor (if the script is run from within Script Editor) is added to the list of notifying apps in System Preferences > Notifications. There, you can configure options, such as whether to display notifications as alerts or banners.
>
> Clicking the Show button in an alert-style notification opens the app that displayed the notification. For a script app, the action of opening the app again triggers the run handler of the script, potentially causing the script to begin processing a second time. Keep this in mind, and add code to your script to handle this scenario, if appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Thank you, this was just what I needed for some user scripts. I made a slight modification to add a subtitle and sound. If a value is not provided, it is ignored.

```
function _sys_notify() {
local notification_command="display notification \"$2\" with title \"$1\" subtitle \"$3\" sound name \"$4\""
osascript -e "$notification_command"
}

alias sys-notify="_sys_notify $1 $2 $3 $4"
```

For the sound, use a sound filename without the extension from /System/Library/Sounds. For example, to use the file Ping.aiff, use Ping for $4

Answer (score 4):

If you want sticky notifications (Vic Jang's comment seems to no longer work, at least in Big Sur), here's a kind of way, use dialog instead of notification:

`osascript -e 'display dialog "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'`

So you could do one `display notification` then follow it up with the dialog.

Also [alerter](https://github.com/vjeantet/alerter) does sticky.

```
$ brew install alerter
$ alerter -message "hi"
```

Comment: Good solution, and you can prevent the `dialog` from blocking your terminal by running in the 'background' : `osascript -e 'display dialog "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"' &`