# Display a notification with AppleScript

Tags: applescript, notifications

I would like to trigger a notification with AppleScript.

I have seen [How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel) but I would like to have a *native* AppleScript solution if it exists.

Answer (score 1):

Growl has an [AppleScript dictionary](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php). I didn't find any way to show a single notification in Notification Center, but they are shown in it by default you've enabled forwarding all notifications.

```
tell application id "com.Growl.GrowlHelperApp"
    register as application "Scripts" all notifications "test" default notifications "test"
    notify with name "test" title "title" description "description" application name "Scripts"
end tell
```