# Cron log to Notification bar

Tags: notifications, cron

I have a couple of cron jobs that I would like to log output to the Notification app in Mountain Lion. I've searched and and figured out how to log cron output by editing the plist file, but nothing specifically about how to integrate into the Notifications app.

Comment: Feel free to edit this to show why / how the liked question is different or what you didn't get from that Q&A to solve your problem. Once it's edited, you can flag it for review and potential re-opening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a third party piece of software to send messages to the Notification Center from command line tools and scripts.

[terminal-notifier](https://github.com/alloy/terminal-notifier) appears to be a popular solution. OSXDaily has an article walking through [how to set terminal-notifier up](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/03/send-an-alert-to-notification-center-from-the-command-line-in-os-x/).

[image: OSXDaily screenshot of terminal-notifier in action]

Alternative methods are covered in the answers to, [how can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel)