# Can I trigger an Automator workflow from a Notification Center alert?

Tags: automator, notifications

I know there are ways to [trigger Notification Center alerts](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel) inside an Automator workflow. I'd like to do the reverse.

I'd like to set up an event listener which, when a particular app emits a Notification Center alert, I can trigger a workflow from it. Is this possible?

I'm running Mavericks.

Comment: Are you looking for a specific notification? If you describe your goal we can try to find alternative solutions.