# How can I show the full notifications in the notification center?

Tags: terminal, notifications

I cannot read the full notification (see attached). How can I?

[image]

Comment: what happens when you click on it?

Comment: The Notification Center closes.

Comment: What app are you sing as notifier, I have not seen that one, but have seen those:  http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/57412/46541

Comment: @Buscar웃 That looks like the OSX Notifications

Comment: @ggundersen what window does OSX make frontmost after this - I think it will ve Terminal if the window has not closed

Comment: @Mark I can see what it looks like, but how do you do it ? I want it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notification Center limits the size of a notification to 256 bytes (see [developer reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9)), so there is no way to expand or change how much of a notification you see (unless you can find some third-party application that disables the limit).

After 256 bytes, the notification will be truncated and the user has to click on the notification to see the rest.

For example, if Mail.app sends you a notification of a new message, you likely won't be able to read the whole message from the notification, so you'll have to click on it to open the message in Mail.

However, if the notification is purely informative and does not point to a specific piece of data within the application, when you click on the notification, it will only open the application or, if it is already running, bring it to the foreground.

Terminal is not a UI-based application, so notifications from it are not going to focus on a specific element. A notification from Terminal will simply open the application because its notifications are plaintext messages from the application that don't point to a specific UI element or piece of data.

Comment: This is still the case in 10.11. Unfortunately.

Comment: The developer reference link (which was for iOS, and may not have applied to macOS anyway) is dead, and I can't find anything in the current docs about such a 256-byte limit.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You cannot. You need to click on the notification to read it.

There is no long answer here.

Comment: When I click on the notification, the entire notification center (the whole bar) scrolls back to the right. I cannot read the full message.