# Where can I read the full notification log text

Tags: macos, notifications

My question is related to [How can I show the full notifications in the notification center?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136004/how-can-i-show-the-full-notifications-in-the-notification-center), but I do not necessarily need to "show" the full notification text, only to acces its content somehow, for example by finding its source log so I can read it with vim/grep, etc.

I'm missing some critical information because the notification text is truncated.

[image]

Where is the macOS log file where I can read all those notifications ?