# Can the macOS Notification Center be made wider?

Tags: macos, notifications

When the text of a notification gets cut off, I keep wanting to make it wider so I can read more.

[image]

Comment: @ankiiiiiii, I mean the side panel.

Comment: @JWWalker, can you provide a picture of an example notification?

Comment: @existingperson: OK, I added an image.

Comment: Found this to discover that the alternate I suggested in edit doesn't work [how-can-i-show-the-full-notifications-in-the-notification-center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/136004/how-can-i-show-the-full-notifications-in-the-notification-center?rq=1)

Comment: In a few years a awesome feature "full screen notification center" will be available and they will call it … dashboard 2.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible on macOS. I looked for how developers deal with notification lengths and I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307748/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-push-notification-alert-text

The discussion mostly seems to imply that developers don't have any control over how the notifications are displayed, but rather just standards they have to conform to. Hope that helps!

Comment: You may be right that it's not possible, but I am not convinced by your reasons.  First, limitations on push notifications do not necessarily apply to local notifications.  Second, the fact that the developer has no control over how they are displayed does not imply that the *user* has no control.