# How to trigger Notification Centre notification from JavaScript?

Tags: terminal, applescript, notifications, macos, javascript

The [other question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel) asks the same but using AppleScript. Apple introduced [JavaScript as a new language](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/releasenotes/InterapplicationCommunication/RN-JavaScriptForAutomation/index.html) for Automation in OS X 10.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Terminal,

```
osascript -l JavaScript -e "app=Application.currentApplication(); app.includeStandardAdditions = true; app.displayNotification('Hello, world', {withTitle: 'Title'})"
```

From Script Editor,

```
app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true
app.displayNotification('Hello, world', {withTitle: 'Title'})
```

Comment: We need to link to the API documentation on the displayNotification function; I don't know what other parameters it accepts.

Comment: The documentation is available in Script Editor's Library under StandardAdditions / User Interaction / displayNotification. The other available options are `subtitle` and `soundName`.