# Alternative ways to set a timer on macOS

Tags: macos, applications, time

I'm trying to set a timer on macOS to no avail, as Siri prompts me to set a reminder instead:

[image: Siri response]

Most, if not all apps found on the Mac App Store don't provide this functionality without being too complicated:

[image: Mac App Store results]

Are there any other apps that can provide the functionality without being too complicated or hard to use?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This free and open-source [Timer app](https://github.com/michaelvillar/timer-app) seems pretty clean and simple. It can be downloaded as the zipped file **Timer.app.zip** in the **Assets** list on the [Releases · michaelvillar/timer-app](https://github.com/michaelvillar/timer-app/releases) page at GitHub.

It can also be installed using brew:

```
brew install --cask michaelvillar-timer
```

**Update**: MacOS Ventura (13) introduced the in-built `Clock` app which works like the one on iOS - providing for Alarms, World clock, Timers and Stopwatch.

[image: Screenshot of Timer app]

Comment: That's more of a pomodoro timer and it's limited to 25 minutes. I sometimes need timer for things like 4 hours (prevent a timeout in an app)

Comment: When I've tested it is not limited to 25 minutes  - you can keep moving the timing ring around as many times as you need.

Comment: It does not support window resizing?

Comment: I don't use brew, so I tried building w/Xcode and it was very easy: 1. github clone/download 2. `cd` into base dir and run `make`

Comment: Tip: if you want a 2 minute timer for example, just tap the `2` key

Answer (score 29):

Here's a little timer shell function. Paste this into Terminal (after you read it and understand it, as always, because pasting random commands from the Internet into Terminal is dangerous):

```
setalarm() {
    sleep $(echo "$1 * 60" | bc)
    say "Beep boop"
}
setalarm .1
```

That's 0.1 minutes (in other words, 6 seconds).

If you want to make the alarm repeat until you press Ctrl+C, then paste this instead:

```
setalarm() {
    sleep $(echo "$1 * 60" | bc)
    for x in $(seq 1000); do say "Beep boop"; sleep 0.5; done
}
setalarm .1
```

Comment: very engineering friendly!

Comment: If you'd like a notification instead of audible alert, you can replace `say "Beep boop"` (in the first function; don't want 1000 notifications) with `osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'` as described [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115373) (thanks @grg)

Comment: I was surprised by bash's concatenation syntax, so here's the osascript command I ended up using: `osascript -e 'display notification "'"$1 minute timer complete"'" with title "Ding!"'`

Comment: Great answer, thanks!  Some small mods: this lets you specify the message to say, and also runs it in the background: `function olt() { secs=$(echo "$1 * 60" | bc); msg="${@:2}"; sleep $secs && say $msg & }`  .  With this in my .bash_profile, I can do `$ olt 0.1 ok stop doing that.` and carry on with the term.  Cheers! z

Answer (score 12):

This isn't necessarily a regular MacOS application, but if you are alright with using the Terminal, [termdown](https://github.com/trehn/termdown) is a really nice Terminal Stopwatch. Starting a timer is very simple. For example, `termdown 1h30m` starts a 1 hour 30 minute timer. [image].

Answer (score 11):

The [built-in](https://ss64.com/osx/leave.html) `leave` command is handy for this sort of thing.

Set to alert after 1 minute:

```
% leave +0001
Alarm set for Wed Jun 23 20:42:22 HST 2021. (pid 15321)
```

Set to alert at 8:45 PM:

```
% leave 2045
Alarm set for Wed Jun 23 20:45:00 HST 2021. (pid 15323)
```

Comment: A curious little built in tool! The terminal app may show a notification indicator when not in focus, but not a popup notification. If you're using the console, the notification may get jumbled in whatever else is happening in there.

Comment: Oh, and it keeps repeating the message until you logout or close the window. A good feature if you really need to leave, but would be annoying for a general timer.

Comment: To end the alarm, other than logout, can also use `kill <pid of leave here>` or `killall leave`

Answer (score 7):

I wrote a countdown timer called **[Super Easy Timer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/super-easy-timer/id1353137878?ls=1&mt=12)** every day for my Pomodoro and writing work sessions.

[image: Set a 20 minute timer]

It can recognize natural language, so that you can set the timer by typing "20 minutes" or "2 days 20 hours and 13 minutes".

You can also update the timer on the fly, or reset it with a keyboard shortcut. (Command + R)

[image: Add and remove time]

And if you have an upcoming meeting, or happy hour, you can type "5pm" to get a countdown to your next event.

[image: 5pm Happy Hour Countdown]

You can [try the timer](http://SuperEasyTimer.com) here, or you can [download it from the Mac App Store.](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/super-easy-timer/id1353137878?ls=1&mt=12)

There are keyboard shortcuts and natural language here:

[image: Super Easy Timer Keyboard Shortcuts]

**Disclaimer:** I created the app because I wasn't happy with the other timer apps I found. I wanted a quick, simple to use, and reliable timer app.

Answer (score 5):

Dont know when they introduced it but macos has an app on board. [image]

Comment: Huh, nice!  In English this is the app "clock.app"  and there seems to be a built-in(?) ShortCut called "Start Timer" (found via Spotlight) that goes and sets it quickly.

Comment: This was introduced in MacOS "Ventura" (13.x)

Answer (score 4):

I like to use [Horo](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/horo-timer-for-menu-bar/id1437226581?mt=12). It's a status bar app

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [timeanddate.com](https://www.timeanddate.com/timer/) to set a timer.

[image: Timer on timeanddate.com]

This utility also includes multiple sounds that will play when the timer ends.

[image: Configuration for timer including end sounds]

It also has other time/date-related utilities as well.

Answer (score 3):

Open any modern web browser (Chrome, Firefox etc), go to google.com and enter "timer" in a search box:
[image: Screenshot from Firefox 98 on Macos, Google set to Dark theme]

It does a nice beep at the end.

PS. I entered this as an answer here because I had the same question, googled it, stumbled upon this page, and after reading it all ended up using the solution I just proposed, because it was the simplest.

Answer (score 2):

Try this: https://www.apimac.com/mac/timer/

It has a clean and easy to use interface. It can be used to start multiple countdown timers, stopwatches as well as set alarms.

You can also set simple tasks instead of just an alarm tone like, open an application or read out some text, etc.

Comment: 50 $ for a timer?

Comment: @LeoUfimtsev, where'd you get that price from? On [this page](https://apimac.onfastspring.com/timerstore), I see $30 for the single-user license (although that is pretty expensive for a timer).

Comment: Sorry, At the moment it's 41 Canadian Dollars. Still, it's just too much for a simple timer application for me.

Answer (score 2):

I use http://www.timer-tab.com and I love it. I don't need multiple timers so its effective at doing its job and staying out of the way. You can run it in your browser. You dont need an app since its web based.

Answer (score 1):

I use a countdowm timer that works great and is simple. It's called **Countdown Widget** and you can select to countdown based on days or time. I'm currently using it to countdown days till baseball season starts again. But it will countdown in seconds as well.

Comment: You've described this inexpensive "Countdown widget" app in the Mac App Store: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/countdown-widget/id506996014?mt=12
According to the review at Mac Informer, countdown in seconds is available by setting a "Time Element" checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is a built-in(?) ShortCut called "Start Timer" (found via Spotlight) that goes and sets it quickly.[image: Spotlight Screenshot]

Answer (score -2):

This little script might be useful for small tasks.

`Copy & Paste` in the Terminal

```
alias timer='for i in `seq 1 65535`; do sleep 1s; clear; echo $i $( echo Seconds ) ;done'
```

Type `timer`