# Can anyone recommend a stop watch or timer which stays always on top?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

My requirements for software or a script are:

- I want to count hours when i am programming or browsing
- Digits should appear on top on every app like browser or editor

Can anyone recommend a stop watch or timer app which  stays always on top on every application for macOS?

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for ways to ask for a software recommendation.

Comment: Top notch answer: Turn on 24 hour time. Change your time to 0:00:00. The stopwatch will count up to 23:59:59 and then it will overflow.

Comment: Checkout my countdown timer: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/329313/27857

Answer (score 4):

[ActivityTimer](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/activity-timer/id808647808?mt=12) is a Timer that's free in App Store and has an option to display countdown time in the *Menu bar* in digital or analog form.

I do not know that it can count up (like a Stopwatch).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If "on top" can mean "stays visible in the menu bar", then Horo is a quite nice, simple timer app, with a free version: https://matthewpalmer.net/horo-free-timer-mac/

Answer (score 2):

I use Apimac Timer, which has a free edition. It can count up (stopwatch), count down (timer), or display the current time. In "iconized" mode, it stays on top of other windows.

[image: Apimac Timer preview]

Edit: Whoops. After some seconds, the free version abandons iconized/always-on-top mode and displays an ad for the paid version.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Harvest](https://getharvest.com), which stays on the menu bar. Tons of options– rounding up or down, billing statements, estimates, etcétera. Free for one person with two projects. I love it. I've been using it for over ten years now. iOS version too, synced.