# Pipe Terminal Output To Notification, If Output Contains Specific Phrase?

Tags: terminal, notifications, monitoring

I have a long series of commands that I run on a semi-regular basis. Sometimes, completion of the commands requires user input via password prompt or other responses and sometimes information is output in the course of these commands that I need to copy to a log elsewhere. Mostly, though, the script can run unattended as it processes its lengthy series of tasks.

I've come across dozens of scripts and tools that will tell you when your command has finished running. But that's not what I need. And I've come across tools that should be able to convert varied output into a notification, but there's no accompanying documentation explaining how to do this.

So, if I wanted to be sent a banner notification through Notification Center every time the phrase "space cats" was output during the running of my command, how would I trigger that notification to be sent?

Comment: Good question! (+1) I don't have an answer now, but I'm interested enough to begin looking as this is something I want to do also. From what I've read so far, there are 2 types of notifications: remote and local. Also, access to the NotCtr is via [Apple Push Notification service (docs here)](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW1). There seems to be [activity on SO re APN](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=push+notification), so that's worth looking at.

Comment: Turns out there are a few Q&A on this topic. Here's [one that was useful and informative](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel)

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you can access the output of your scripts. Then you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Replace the echo with your script
echo "space cats" | grep "space cats"

if [[ "$?" -eq "0" ]]; then
    osascript -e 'display notification "Attention!" with title "Notification" subtitle "I found space cats" sound name "Submarine"'
fi
```

Comment: Love it (+1). An alternative to `osascript` may be the `Run Shell Script` action from the Automator application. It seems that `osascript` is summoned by a shell script, whereas `Run Shell Script` action summons a shell script. Based on the paucity of resources Apple has devoted to `osascript`, it seems their strong preference is for developers to use an "Apple-centric" (and therefore less open) approach to shell programming. A bit hypocritical of them perhaps, given that they tout their [Unix roots](https://www.wired.com/2013/08/jordan-hubbard/) when it suits their narrative.