# How to trigger an action when mac displays a notification from specific application?

Tags: notifications, automation

i am looking to trigger an action when a notification appears from my web browser.
basically i want to click on the notification automatically when it appears.
happy for this to be in Automator or Keyboard maestro.

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel/115373

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel)

Comment: These are the opposite of what OP is asking. They want to trigger a script based on a notification, not fire a notification from a script.