# “terminal-notifier.app” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified

Tags: macos, terminal, monterey, gatekeeper

When I update os from `Big Sur` to `Monterey` and open `terminal-notifier.app` it shows me the message

**“terminal-notifier.app” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.**

Why it shows me the messages

Comment: Or just use `osascript -e 'display notification "Hello World"'`. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57412/how-can-i-trigger-a-notification-center-notification-from-an-applescript-or-shel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Navigate to the application in Finder
- Right-click it and select "Open"
- Confirm in the dialog which will be shown

It should work as before from now on.

Answer (score 0):

terminal-notifier doesn't seem to be maintained anymore, you can try out the more updated [Nudge Notifier](https://NudgeNotifier.com) instead.

Besides Mac it can also forward notifications to Slack, Discord, and iMessage among some other neat features.