# Notify when time-consuming task is finished in the terminal

Tags: macos, big-sur, notifications

Is there a way to get notified when some terminal task is finished "in the background" in the terminal?
I need to get notified when `npm run build` is over which can take up to 15 mins. I've considered using `iTerm2` as well as adding `terminal-notifier` commands to my `package.json` but none are suitable enough.

Can this be achieved by some native OSX features?

Comment: Sorry, this is an answer, but I seem only to be able to comment:

At least on macOS Monterey one can issue from the terminal or a shell script:

     *** osascript -e 'display notification "text" with title "text" sound name "default"'***

To allow such notification one must go to "System preferences–Notifications & Focus–Script Editor" and select "Allow Notifications", and "Alerts" (display for three seconds) or "Banners" (display until closed). For silent ones, omit 'sound name "default"'.

Comment: Thank you @KristjanJonasson - could you [post your answer as an answer there](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/9412/5472), please? This thread is closed to new answers and you are correct that you have a proper answer and not a comment.

Comment: Have done so. See now my answer to a similar [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/446838/473180)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to invoke a notification using Applescript after a given terminal command like so:

`npm run build && osascript -e 'display notification "Complete" with title "npm run build"'`

The next level would be to create a custom script in `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "build-notify": "npm run build && osascript -e 'display notification \"Complete\" with title \"npm run build\"'"
}
```

Another option would be to create a custom alias to run the whole thing:
`alias build="npm run build && osascript -e 'display notification \"Complete\" with title \"Build complete\"'"`
Then run it like a regular terminal command: `build`

If you don't mind the audio, you could use the `say` command instead:
`npm run build && say done`.

There are also some tools that abstract this a bit, like https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier and maybe many more.